# Store seekbar values in array

Tags: android, arrays, radio-button, android-seekbar

I want to store seek bar values that user selects by dragging thumb, in an array

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
private ArrayList<Seekbar> mSeekbars = new ArrayList<Seekbar>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// Your code where you set the content view
mSeekbars.add(((Seekbar) findViewById(R.id.seekbar1));
mSeekbars.add(((Seekbar) findViewById(R.id.seekbar2));
mSeekbars.add(((Seekbar) findViewById(R.id.seekbar3));
}

// To enable seekbars
private void onRadioButtonSelected() {
for (Seekbar seekbar : mSeekbars) {
seekbar.setEnabled(true);
}
}

// To get seekbar values
private ArrayList<Integer> saveSeekbarValues() {
ArrayList<Integer> values = new ArrayList<Integer>();
   for (Seekbar seekbar : mSeekbars) {
      values.add(seekbar.getProgress())
    }
return values;
}

}
```

One other solution is to have a parent layout that holds all seekbars and enable/disable that layout instead of enabling/disable the individual seekbars. However, for the values, you will have to manually retrieve each seekbar's value.

Answer (score 0):

You can put all seekbars in single view and get one by one child using iteration, and setEnable() them:-

```
    // to enable seekbars

    public void enableAllSeekBars()
    {
        int childcount = containerView.getChildCount();
        for (int i=0; i < childcount; i++){
              if(containerView.getChildAt(i) instanceof SeekBar)
              {
                 SeekBar sb = (SeekBar)containerView.getChildAt(i);
                 sb.setEnabled(true);
              }
          }
    }


    // to get seekbar values

    public ArrayList<Integer> getSeekBarValues()
    {
      ArrayList<Integer> values = new ArrayList<Integer>();
      int childcount = containerView.getChildCount();
      for (int i=0; i < childcount; i++){
              if(containerView.getChildAt(i) instanceof SeekBar)
              {
                 SeekBar sb = (SeekBar)containerView.getChildAt(i);
                 values.add(sb.getProgress())
              }
      }

    return values;
    }
```

Comment: yes, and what about storing seekbar values in the array

Comment: what is containerView ? moreover i dnt understand, like in array there is index, what about arraylist i dnt see index kind of thing in your code